# What happens if "..." is placed before a Java variable name?

Tags: java, variables

I was just experimenting with variable names when I realized this:-

```
int n; //this is a valid name
int .n; //this is a invalid name
int ..n; //this is a invalid name
int ...n; //this is a valid name
```

Comment: Basically `int[] n;`

Answer (score 1):

The special token `...` is to declare var-args parameters in method signatures, as in

```
void foo(String... bars){}
```

So in your example, it gets parsed differently (as `int... n`), and is not considered part of the variable name.

But it is still invalid syntax, comparable to `int +n;` or `int (n;`, because the token does not make sense here.